# log4net ThreadContext alternative to add custom property

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a class where I added a custom property to the ThreadContext to log the information.

```
class MyClass
{
    private ILog myLog = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));
    public MyClass()
    {
        log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["ABC"] = "Foobar";
    }
}
```

I could successfully log with %property{ABC} in the pattern and it is working fine.

But instances of MyClass are used in different contexts, so ABC is not necessarily set on the same ThreadContext that executes myLog.Info(), as a consequence, it's sometimes null.

Is there another way than using the ThreadContext?

I am looking for an elegant way to automatically inject this ABC property to the logger. So every time a message is logged this property should be available to the appender. Developers should not care about it at the time when they log something. They should just consume the logger as they are used to.

Comment: I support a library called CorrelatorSharp that does this sort of thing https://github.com/CorrelatorSharp/CorrelatorSharp/blob/master/CorrelatorSharp/ActivityTracker.cs check out the code we use to store the `CorrelationId` for logging.

Comment: We then use a framework's layout engine https://github.com/CorrelatorSharp/CorrelatorSharp.Logging.NLog/blob/be5290003c24dc4990d5c538e8e0e37548a33cb1/CorrelatorSharp.Logging.NLog/LoggerAdaptor.cs#L29 here is nLog.

Comment: `ThreadContext` is not safe in an async/await type world. So. Beware.

Comment: Why you are not using `log4net.GlobalContext.Properties` instead?